# Copy list item to another list along with the attachment

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to copy a list item from one list to an other along with the file attachments which are associated with it.

I am doing this in a custom workflow. I am trying to make a object of a class which is coming from `Listdata.svc` and the class is of TasksItem.

```
TasksItem newtask = new TasksItem()
{
  Title = workflowProperties.Item.Title,
};
```

Above is the code which is working fine when copy only simple field like Title of the task etc but I want to know how can we add attachments into it. So the attachments will also get copied to the destination list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy the attachment You can use the following code:

```
foreach (string filename in item.Attachments)
{
  var file =  item
               .ParentList
               .ParentWeb
               .GetFile(item.Attachments.UrlPrefix + fileName);
  var imageData = file.OpenBinary();
  newItem.Attachments.Add(fileName, imageData);
}
newItem.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newTask.Attachments.Add(attachmentName, attachmentData);
```

where attachmentData is a byte-array. You can easily convert attachments to byte[] and add to items.

Check out( warning: error in code sample): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spattachmentcollection.aspx

Comment: How to get the attached file from "workflowproperties.item", let me know.

Comment: I m getting 
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: args on setsavestream method of datacontext

Comment: It should be in workflowproperties.Item.Attachments, no?